# Can i use the GET api call and pass the values in the header and receive a response in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Need to pass the trans_dict and expected response is {"transid": "1223344"}

Below is my code.

```
trans_dict = [{"id": "employee1@gmail.com",
  "type": "email"},
   {"id": "123456",
  "type": "phone"}]

def mytransaction():
    payload = json.dumps(trans_dict)
    url = ""
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8"))
    else:
        return None
    mytransaction = my_trans()
```

Comment: You are calling function from inside(that too with a wrong name), is it intentional?

Comment: edited the same